# SQL Count by Active Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a table of records and active/inacitve dates, is there a simple way to count active records by month?  For example:

```
tbl_a
id        dt_active    dt_inactive
a         2013-01-01   2013-08-24
b         2013-01-01   2013-07-05
c         2012-02-01   2012-01-01
```

If I have to generate an output of active records by month like this:
active:  dt_active < first_day_of_month <= dt_inactive

```
month    count
2013-01  2
2013-02  2
2013-03  2
2013-04  2
2013-05  2
2013-06  2
2013-07  2
2013-08  1
2013-09  0
```

Is there any clever way to do this besides uploading a temp table of dates and using subqueries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method that gives the count of actives on the beginning of the month.  It creates a list of all the months and then joins this information to `tbl_a`.

```
with dates as (
      select cast('2013-01-01' as date) as month
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, dates.month)
      from dates
      where month < cast('2013-09-01' as date)
)
select convert(varchar(7), month, 121), count(a.id)
from dates m left outer join
     tbl_a a
     on m.month between a.dt_active and a.dt_inactive
group by convert(varchar(7), month, 121)
order by 1;
```

Note:  if `dt_inactive` is the first date of inactivity, then the `on` clause should be:

```
on m.month >= a.dt_active and m.month < a.dt_inactive
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b61da/2) is a SQL Fiddle with the working query.

Comment: This is pretty cool, thank you.  I would not have known how to use `WITH` and was uploading a table.