# Count active system by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, null

I have a [System] Table whit an ContractDateEnd field. If this value is null the System is "active"

My goal is to calculate the number of system actives by months for current year

So, for every month I have to sum a system if ContractEndDate = NULL or Month(ContractEndDate) >= Month number

```
Create  TABLE Systems (
[ID] int,
[ContractStartDate] date,
[ContractEndDate] date)

INSERT INTO Systems ([ID], [ContractStartDate], [ContractEndDate])
VALUES 
(1, '1/1/2018', '08/30/2020'),
(2, '1/1/2019', '05/31/2020'),
(3, '1/6/2020', NULL)
```

I've managed to have the active months by system id

```
ID January February March April May June July August September October November December
1    1        1        1    1    1   1    1     1       0        0        0        0
2    1        1        1    1    1   0    0     0       0        0        0        0
3    1        1        1    1    1   1    1     1       1        1        1        1
```

But i would like to have this:

```
 Month        Total

 January       3
 February      3
 March         3
 April         3
 May           3
 June          2
 July          2
 August        2
 September     1
 October       1
 November      1
 December      1
```

This solution [SQL Count by Active Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749891/sql-count-by-active-date) use Join but do not count nulls..

How can I do?

Thanks 
Marco

Comment: I don't understand.  You reference months with no years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to use this query:

```sql
SELECT Month = DATENAME(MONTH, DATEFROMPARTS(2000, MonthNumber, 1)),
       Sum   = SUM(IIF(MonthNumber <= ISNULL(MONTH(Systems.ContractEndDate), 12), 1, 0))
FROM (
     VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
) AS Months (MonthNumber)
CROSS JOIN #Systems AS Systems
GROUP BY MonthNumber
```